# Compare specific list element with other elements

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list as:

`L=[9, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]`

Now, I want to compare 3rd element of the list `i.e 7` with remaining elements as whether they are greater then given number or not.

Expected output:

```
['yes','yes','equal','no','no','no','no']
```

Comment: It is required on SO to demonstrate the effort of solving the issue you are asking the community to help you with. Where is your attempt?

Comment: You have to show your effort and put your code when you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function like this:

```
In [1320]: def compare_elements(element, lst):
      ...:     ans = []
      ...:     for i in lst:
      ...:         if i > element:
      ...:             ans.append('yes')
      ...:         elif i < element:
      ...:             ans.append('no')
      ...:         else:
      ...:             ans.append('equal')
      ...:     return ans
      ...:
```

Call the function like below. Pass the list and the element to compare against to the function:

```
In [1312]: L=[9, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]

In [1321]: res = compare_elements(L[2], L)
In [1323]: res
Out[1323]: ['yes', 'yes', 'equal', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no']
```

Comment: @Learner Let me know if this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

**List comprehension using if else statement** should do it.

```
newlist = ["Yes" if item > L[2] else "No" if item < L[2] else "Equal" for item in L]
print (newlist)

:: ['Yes', 'Yes', 'Equal', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No']
```

Comment: Seems similar to my answer except for the rearrangement of the conditions :)

Comment: @Sruthi V, your answer matches but he might not want to hardcode the number '7' since it could be any other number in the list. Comparing it with the position is a better approach.

Comment: That seems like a tiny change that should've been left as a comment in my answer don't you think XD XD (nvm kidding)

Comment: Actually, your answer didn't load until I posted mine :P 
Also, I don't have enough rep to comment on other users' answers at the moment :(

Comment: @Sruthi V, I see you've edited your answer to match xD